# Setting a cookie in codeigniter 4 is not working

Tags: php, codeigniter, cookies

I'm currently working on a project where I have to migrate it from codeigniter version 3 to version 4. When setting a cookie, the following code was originally used:

```
$cookie = array(
    'name'   => 'admin_id',
    'value'  => $result['id'],
    'expire' => '216250',
    'domain' => '',
    'path'   => '/',
    'prefix' => '',
    'secure' => FALSE
);
$this->input->set_cookie($cookie);
```

According to the [docs](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/cookie_helper.html?highlight=set_cookie#set_cookie), the way to set a cookie in version 4 is by the following code:

```
set_cookie($cookie);
```

Note that the `$cookie` variable is still the same.

This cookie is being set in the Model file and then a redirect is called in the following way:

```
return redirect()->to('/');
```

I'm aware that cookies are only set after a page is being redirected and therefore I'm trying to retrieve it in another controller. However, the cookie is not being set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
use withCookies()

return redirect()->to('/')->withCookies();
```

see https://github.com/codeigniter4/CodeIgniter4/issues/3939